# device naming zfs vs smartctl vs iostat

Tags: zfs, iostat, omnios

I'm working on gathering performance metric data from a SAN (5.11 omnios-7648372 ).
we use dataon JBOD.

a snip of Output of zdb -C mypoolname   :

```
children[0]:
    type: 'disk'
    id: 0
    guid: 7701924650939559899
    path: '/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0'
    devid: 'id1,sd@n5000c5004cce9b53/a'
    phys_path: '/pci@0,0/pci8086,25f7@2/pci8086,350c@0,3/pci1000,3030@1/sd@0,0:a'
    whole_disk: 1
    DTL: 599
    create_txg: 4
```

Focusing at the 'path' part, it say '/dev/dsk/c1t0d0s0' I asume the device name is c1t0d0s0 and it 'match' with smartctl ... unless smart ctl said the path is /dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s0

But 'iostat -extnc 3 1' naming the device differently : c1t0d0

Kindly please tell me why the 3 of them did not use the same name for one same device ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zdb` is showing you the `path` that ZFS uses internally to address the device, which is a path in the `/dev` filesystem that allows access to the block device file. (By the way, `zdb` is mainly meant as a debugging tool, and isn’t guaranteed to have backward compatibility for anything it prints.) It's addressing using the [disk slice](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5093/disksconcepts-20068/index.html) suffix `s0`, which is why that appears in those listings. I believe disk slices are basically the same as partitions. Slice 0 is usually the whole disk when you're using ZFS, since when you add an entire device into your `zpool`, ZFS will automatically format the device for you and it only needs / creates one slice. However, it's also possible to add just a single partition of a disk to your `zpool` (or even more stupidly, multiple partitions on the same drive as separate `vdevs`), so ZFS has to track which partition(s) it's actually in control of.

`iostat` is showing you just the device name, without the `/dev` path or the slice number. This is because `iostat` doesn't know about slices, and it just looks at the actual device when it collects its data.

I don't know what's up with `smartctl`. I would expect it to work at the device level like `iostat`, but maybe it's getting data passed to it through ZFS, which uses the slice number. This seems like a bug to me, since ideally you would have errors being reported in the smallest failure domain that they’re a part of, which in this case is the disk. (Although at least it’s easy to work around.)

Comment: Sir, could you please tell me what more proper command to get device tree.

Comment: @BinoOetomo Most people look at output from the zpool command to get the device list / structure. There is also libzfs for accessing it programmatically (in C or a language where you can call C functions). To get the full device tree on Solaris-based systems, use prtconf and libdevinfo.